# Soldering to output pins on AC-DC linear power supply

Tags: power-supply, soldering

I have a linear [AC-DC power supply](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/International-Power/IHAD15-04?qs=0xCm9DOQnC6xCpeYcfqucA%3D%3D) with output pins that require soldering

[Datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/199/InternationalPower_IHAD15-0.4-1286610.pdf)

What is the proper way to do it, maybe an example of final result?

[image]

Comment: Aren't those 2mm banana plugs?

Comment: What does the product documentation advise? Fix the mouser link too.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell from the picture and the datasheet is near with the details, but those look like they could be turret terminals.  Search for "turret solder" and you'll find some videos and diagrams.  Big things are your wire should wrap at least 180 degrees around the post, preferably 270 degrees and the solder fillet should cover at least 75% of the contact area.  The insulation of your wire should end 1-2 conductor diameters away from where the conductor contacts the post.

Comment: There's a section on soldering to turret terminals in the [NASA Training Program Student Workbook for Hand Soldering](https://protostack.com.au/download/NASA%20Student%20Handbook%20for%20Hand%20Soldering.pdf).

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for: nobody in my circle knew what to google.

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica You should reach for "ipc turret soldering". IPC is the relevant industry standard. The above NASA document seems rather outdated (pre-RoHS) and NASA likely don't give a damn about RoHS since they have very specialized requirements.